# SFSE Users Presenting at DF 2016: When, What Topic & Where?

Tags: discussion

For those of you who are presenting at DF16, please share with us the title of your presentation, when your presentation is planned for and where it will be held (if you know). I'm confident our members would be interested in learning about your presentation and supporting you if they can.

I just learned a couple days ago that I'll be presenting on User Groups Giving Back to their Community on Tuesday Morning sometime between 8 AM and 10:30 AM in the session for User Groups. Being as I only learned about this a couple days ago, the actual title of my presentation is yet TBD. During my presentation, I'll be sharing what the [DallasDevloperGroup has learned standing-up NPSP Orgs](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/05/setting-charity-non-profit-starter-pack.html) and our new [DallasGiveForce](http://www.dallasgiveforce.com) program which we'll be launching very soon.

So, let's hear about other's presentations!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's make this a wiki.

**Tuesday October 4th.**

- 8.00  - in the User Group session: User Groups Giving Back to their Community by [crmprogdev](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2212/crmprogdev)
- 12.00 - [Introduction To Lightning LockerService](https://success.salesforce.com/Sessions?eventId=a1Q3000000qQOd9EAG#/session/a2q3A000000LBdBQAW) by [JF Paradis](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/21000/jf-paradis)
- 12.45 - [Lightning Chess, the Fun Way to Learn the Lightning Component Framework](http://bit.ly/LightningChess-DF) by [Lieven Juwet](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/10280/lieven-juwet?tab=profile) & [Samuel De Rycke](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/119/samuel-de-rycke?tab=profile)
- 3.30 - [Clean Apex Code with Automatic Code Metrics](https://success.salesforce.com/sessions?eventId=a1Q3000000qQOd9EAG#/session/a2q3A000000LBR7QAO) by [Robert Sösemann](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/256/robert-s%C3%B6semann) and [Lorenzo Frattini](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/25214/lorenzo)

**Wednesday October 5th.**

- 10:30 to 11:10 AM - [Building App Cloud Mobile Extensions with Swift](https://success.salesforce.com/Sessions#/session/a2q3A000000LBRaQAO) by [Gaurav Kheterpal](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/10881/gaurav-kheterpal) at Moscone West, 2024
- 11.30 - [Analyzing Salesforce Data with Heroku, Kafka, and Connect](https://success.salesforce.com/Sessions?eventId=a1Q3000000qQOd9#/session/a2q3A000000LBeAQAW) by [alouie](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/1099/alouie)
- 1.30 PM - [From Awesome Admin to Champion Coder](https://success.salesforce.com/Sessions?eventId=a1Q3000000qQOd9#/session/a2q3A000000sWTgQAM) by [Jenny B](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/10038/jenny-b)

**Thursday October 6th.**

- 10.00 AM - [Introduction to Lightning Out](https://success.salesforce.com/Sessions#/session/a2q3A000000LBmVQAW) Breakout Session By Mohith Shrivastava
- 2.00 PM - [How and Why to use Javascript Promises in Lightning Compoments](https://success.salesforce.com/Sessions?eventId=a1Q3000000qQOd9#/session/a2q3A000000LBS1QAO) Breakout Session by [minige](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/5331/minige)

  ..

**Friday October 7th.**

- 10:00 AM - [Lightning Strikes: Embrace the Change in Your Org](https://success.salesforce.com/Sessions#/session/a2q3A000000sWTxQAM) by [Gaurav Kheterpal](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/10881/gaurav-kheterpal) at Admin Meadow Theatre

Comment: Awesome list! Added mine. I'm doing 2 this year (apart from one which is customer-centric).